# How can make animations happends using grid

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function collapse() {
  var menu = document.querySelector(".Menu");
  document.getElementsByClassName("cont")[0].classList.toggle("collapsed");
  if (menu.style.display == "none") {
    menu.style.removeProperty("display");
  } else {
    menu.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.cont {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 1fr 50px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "Header Header Header"
    "Menu Main Main"
    "Menu Footer Footer";
  height: 100vh;
  background: blue;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.collapsed {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 1fr 50px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "Header Header Header"
    "Main Main Main"
    "Footer Footer Footer";
  height: 100vh;
  background: blue;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.cont div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.Header {
  grid-area: Header;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.Menu {
  grid-area: Menu;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.Main {
  grid-area: Main;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.Footer {
  grid-area: Footer;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont" class="cont">
  <div class="Header">Header</div>
  <div class="Menu">Menu</div>
  <div class="Main"><button onclick="collapse()">toggle Sidebar</button></div>
  <div class="Footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

I want to make the changes happens slowly so i can see them changes but the thing is they happen fast even I tried to use transition with different values can someone suggest any options to add  I tried chat GPT butt it's not working” can be due to reasons like he's not into that level of understanding

Comment: ChatGPT is a story-writing service that will lie in order to write a credible story, so if you're going to use an AI system to help you write code: pick a better one. ChatGPT is _designed_ to lie, in a way that makes it sound like it's not. Having said that: what is this supposed to do? Please [read the posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask) and then [edit] your post so that it starts by saying what you wanted to make, then shows the code _you wrote_ to do that, then talks about what you expect to happen when  you perform specific actions, what it does instead, and how you debugged that.

Comment: Transition is not working because `display` property is not compatibile with transitions.